# Can't get parameters into a model in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i'm working with bitrix24 outbond webhooks, they send me information throughthe parameters so i'm using

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.QueryString.Value);
```

And i'm getting

```
{document_id[0]=crm&document_id[1]=CCrmDocumentDeal&document_id[2]=DEAL_618&auth[domain]=curso.bitrix24.com&auth[client_endpoint]=https%3a%2f%2fcurso.bitrix24.com%2frest%2f&auth[server_endpoint]=https%3a%2f%2foauth.bitrix.info%2frest%2f&auth[member_id]=26fa94f0ade07c047c5cf35e4213d42d}
```

How can i tranform this into a model?

Answer (score 0):

`ParseQueryString` gives you a [`NameValueCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection?view=netcore-3.1). You can simply access the keys if you know what they are and assign the value to the correct property of some object.

You have not shown your class definition, but this is the basic idea. You will need to cast or `.ToString()` some values to proper data types.

```
var nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.QueryString.Value);

var someobj = new SomeClass();

someobj.SomeProperty = nameValueCollection["the key that corresponds to property SomeProperty"];

someobj.AnotherProperty = nameValueCollection["the key that corresponds to property AnotherProperty"];

// ...etc.
```